# How to override a class to add functionality in Django

Tags: python, django, overriding

Lets say I want to override a class in form_designer/admin.py which is installed in my virtualenv. In this file is a class named FormAdmin, to which I want to add the class media, like so:

```
class FormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    class Media:
        # Media options
```

I would prefer not to touch the file in the virtualenv, because doing updates would be a pain.

I have tried to make a local folder called form_designer, which contains only the file admin.py. In this file I import the form_designer.admin and made a new class which extends the original FormAdmin class. This didn't work as I hoped.

I'm quite new with python, so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate - `This didn't work as I hoped.` Give exact error messages, etc.

Comment: Well, you seem to have successfully created the subclass, but have you actually used it anywhere? Have you registered it with the admin, for example?

Comment: have you unregistered the original ModelAdmin?

Comment: I figured it out, I put the subclass in my main-app's admin, where I unregistered and registered this subclass. Turns out I overcomplicated it. Thanks for your help!